# Can I pass a template parameter into a MediaWiki TemplateStyles stylesheet?

Tags: mediawiki

I want to style responsive images in MediaWiki. (I am running mediawiki 1.34.1 and I have the TemplateStyles extension installed.) Some Googling lead me to create a `Template:ResponsiveImage` like:

```
<templatestyles src="ResponsiveImage/style.css" />
<div class="responsive-image">
{{{1}}}
</div>
```

with a style sheet `Template:ResponsiveImage/style.css` like:

```
/* To make images responsive */
.responsive-image img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

So far so good. I can do `{{ResponsiveImage|[[File:some image.png]]}}` and it fits across the full screen width and shrinks with the screen size.

But it would be neat to be able to pass `max-width` to give other responsive width images, but I can't find any documentation or examples of how to do it. I've tried the obvious - `max-width:{{{1}}};` - but just get an error

```
Invalid or unsupported value for property 
max-width
at line 3 character 12.
```

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Of course if there's some other way to style responsive images of arbitrary percentage widths then that would solve my problem.

Comment: It seems that "templates" containing CSS stylesheets are not real templates, and `{{{1}}}` is not parsed there.

Comment: You can try to assemble a list of images by Lua, adding `style="max-width: (your parametre)"` to each image.

Comment: Parameters in TemplateStyles are not supported. You could use `attr()` but browser support is limited. Or you can use inline styles as suggested above but then that property cannot depend on screen size.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that inline styling like `<div style="max-width:100%; height:auto;">[[File:myimage.png]]</div>` doesn't work. (This is documented on [mediawiki support desk](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Tuubagqalz9vk2m9))